# ExtJS - Handling Session Management

Tags: session, extjs, panel, containers

I want to know how i can save page data.first i will tell how my application works.
I have a container and i am adding panels to this dynamically.
something like this
--container
--add panel_1
---want to add panel_2 ? remove panel_1 and add panel_2 in that place

My problem is..Now i am planning to have a back button in panel 2..when user clicks ,will take him to panel_1 and i want to show what he entered...Please help me

have seen this ([Extjs 4 Session Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019902/extjs-4-session-management))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an extra class with static members for holding data in MVC arch in ExtJS. So I save objects, arrays, vars etc in it from controller and use them later in project. Perhaps this help you as well. Save panel_1 object or data and goto panel_2, or viceversa
e.g.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Utility', {
statics : {
              panel1: false,
              panel2: false,

              myFun : function() {
                 //some code
              }
            }
          });
```

in any controller/view etc whenever you want to save an object or value, refer to this class but first add to require. .e.g.

```
var ut = MyApp.controller.Utility;
ut.panel1 = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('panel')[0];
```

Comment: Thanks @TheRaaz for ur reply.....i would really appreciate if u could point me to some example...